# How to display Playa Info inside of Matrix

Tags: matrix, playa

I am missing something very simple.

I have a Matrix field pulling in content from a Playa field.

Lets say my Matrix cells are called {cell_1}, {cell_2} and so on.
Each cell is a Playa field and I simply want to dispaly the content of {cell_1}, which is a Playa field.

How do I get my Playa info to display correctly for each cell?
Currently I am able to pull information in from my Playa field but its not showing the specific information I need.
{cell_1} should show me SPEAKER_A but it shows me SPEAKER_A, SPEAKER_B and so on.

I know I am missing something very simple and any help would be appreciated.

I think the answer I was looking for was removed from the docs when the P&T site was recently updated.

Oh yeah using:
EE 2.5.2,
Matrix 2.4.1, and
Playa 4.1.0.3

Thanks in advance!

John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is basically how you retrieve Playa relationship values within a Matrix cell:

```
{matrix_field_name}

    {!-- Your Playa field inside the Matrix --}
    {playa_field}
        {title} {!-- Desired value to retrieve from the relationship --}
    {/playa_field}

    {!-- Any other Matrix cells can be retrieved in the matrix tag pair --}
    {other_matrix_cell} 

{/matrix_field_name}
```

Comment: Apply that to your particular code example. If you're still having problems then update your question with your particular code block and I'll take a look.

Comment: Thanks Ian! That worked, knew I am was missing something simple I was missing. I was actually over complicating everything.

Comment: Thanks from me also Ian! I too was over-complicating things. I swear Matrix and Playa are based on dark magic. They are fabulously great. Easier to use than EE itself. Have a great day! CJ

Answer (score 0):

For those who is still struggling or not sure where and what should be my answer is:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="ONE"}

{matrix}

<!--Playa from channel TWO--> 
    {your_playa var_prefix="any_prefix_you_like"} 

    <!--Matrix inside playa-->
      {any_prefix_you_like:matrix_name field="PLAYA_FIELD"}

           <!--Playa inside matrix--> 

          {any_prefix_you_like:deep_playa}<!--Playa inside playa of matrix from channel THREE-->

            <!--Playa inside matrix-->

      {/any_prefix_you_like:matrix_name}
     <!--Matrix inside playa-->

    {/your_playa} 
<!--Playa from channel-->

{/matrix}

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

I have spent whole week figuring out how to pull data from 3 different places and mixing them together in reports for client. Enjoy!